# Why could a browser change the domain typed into URL instead of fetching page?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

[edit: the culprit was the HTTPS Everywhere extension. I'm not sure what to do with the question in this case, as I feel it could be useful for others, but rephrasing the question to be specific to an extension seems like it may make it off-topic]

It appears my Chrome browser is fetching

```
http://data.sublimevideo.net/js/hlh35zoa.js (a 301 redirect)
```

when I point it to

```
http://cdn.sublimevideo.net/js/hlh35zoa.js (a JS file)
```

as well as [any other path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbpST.png) on that domain. tcpdump shows there is no connection ever made to cdn.sublimevideo.net

This does not happen in incognito mode, but clearing "Cached images and files" in the "Clear browsing data" screen does not help.

Errors reported on my site's JS error aggregator point to something similar happening to a non-negligible portion of my Firefox users (across all versions), as well as Chrome users (across all versions), and Opera 23, although a fresh install of Firefox does not appear to have this issue.

I've tried disabling the cache in Chrome's dev tools, which stops the 301 redirect at data.sublimevideo.net from being cached, but does nothing to the `cdn -> data` translation the browser appears to be doing before that.

I am using Chrome 37 on OS X 10.9.4 without Flash or Java installed.

What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: If you add a querystring to the url (eg http://cdn.sublimevideo.net/js/hlh35zoa.js?abcd) is it still redirecting and caching?

Comment: Yes, it is still renaming the domain. Actually, all paths on the cdn subdomain are getting renamed to the data subdomain.

Comment: So the problem was caused by HTTPS Everywhere extension?

Comment: Yes. Not sure if the question is worth keeping around, as a fix should be incoming: https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/issues/144